# Unsubscribe live query in OrientJS

Tags: orientdb, livequery, orientjs

I use OrientJS with OrientDB to perform livequery. The subscription to live query has no problem but I could not find any way to unsubscribe from that event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will unsubscribe from the token which is returned on initializing the live query.

`live unsubscribe ${token}`

This token is acquired by using the returned data from the liveQuery resolver.

```
db.liveQuery(QUERY, {
  resolver: (a, b) => {
    const token = _.first(a).token;
      return a;
  },
})
```

Please note that you have to include `return a` to not break the built-in resolver.